# Performance difference between using check and a enum type?

Tags: mariadb

What is the performance difference between using a check instead of a enum to make sure a value in the column doesn't exceed X?

For recent mariadb setups

Comment: most likely very little. But it should be able to run a small benchmark to find out.

Comment: *What is the performance difference* Performance diff for what process precisely? the answer "in general" not exists. *using a check instead of a enum to make sure a value in the column doesn't exceed X* Provide according CREATE TABLE scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`ENUM` lets you specify the possible values.  But if you use a value out of that set, what happens?  It might be silently set to the 'first' value.  Or it might give an warning that you are not noticing.

An `ENUM` is a datatype that takes 1 byte.  (Or in rare cases 2 bytes.)

`CHECK` is not a datatype, but active code that lets you explicitly cause an error.  It can be applied to any(?) datatype.

I don't see anough "performance" difference to matter.  Instead, use the technique that works better for you and your app.

Comment: I was just curious about the performance impact of using either, in a column that receives  thousands of updates/sec

Comment: At that level of detail, I don't know. Suggest you test both approaches and supply an answer.